# How to make PHP debugging process?

Tags: php, debugging

I am trying to make a conditional PHP debugger tool, that, when called, will write certain steps in execution like a position in code which corresponds to a function or level.

I formed it as:

```
define("DEBUGGING", TRUE); //IF TRUE, TURNS ON CONDITIONAL CODE THAT RETURNS CODE FLOW
```

and

```
if (DEBUGGING) { echo "RETURN LINE OF CODE OR SOMETHING ELSE"; }
```

which I insert where needed.

Is there a better way to do this? I did turn all PHP warning levels ON, but that is not enough as I don't know which part of the code was executed due to redundant functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of needlessly cluttering up your code you should just install [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org).

This will output full stack traces in HTML format when there is an error in your code.

Here is an output example I found via google:

[image: Xdebug output example]

Also, Xdebug provides remote debugging so that you can use a real debugger (I use [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)) to step through your code.

Comment: Thanks! Does X-Debug also return results for execution of good code? - The reason I ask, is because I have a redundant functions that account to various fail situations, and account for one another. That means that if I don't know which part of the code was precisely executed, I can not precisely know is the code really works or not. Thanks.

Comment: use try catch and throw an exception

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.  Surely the result of executing good code is that your application works?  If you want to confirm the code execution path you can add something like `echo __FILE__ . ': ' . __LINE__;` in various places.  This will output the exact location where it is placed.  But this would be more easily done by stepping through with a real debugger.

Comment: I think the OP wants a stacktrace, so they can check that redundant code is not being executed.  I suggest using exceptions to handle your errors.

Comment: In the end, I ended adding echo __FILE__ comments. I needed to check for each contingency on a working code. Nothing else I tried worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to get a stack trace easily

```
try{
    throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception $e ){
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

This will give you a real nice stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks; will implement!